# .htaccess www.mydomain.com/index.php?page=home to www.mydomain.com/home

Tags: php, .htaccess

how do I setup med .htaccess file, so it will rewrite www.mydomain.com/index.php?page=home to www.mydomain.com/home?

I have tried this piece of code, but it doesn't like i want.

RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /

```
    # Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php?page= [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php [L,QSA]


    # Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first redirect rule in not right. You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```